# On divergence of convergent looking integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

How is $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{e^{1/x}}$ divergent? By ocular inspection it looks to me as if the lower limit doesn't cause any problems and neither does the upper limit as $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-1/x}=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"as $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-1/x}=1$" is *precisely* the problem: since there exists $M>1$ such that $\forall x>M,\, e^{-1/x}>\frac12$, you have that, as soon that $t>M$, $$\int_1^t e^{-1/x}\,dx\ge \frac12(t-M)+\int_1^M e^{-1/x}\,dx=\frac{t-M}2+c$$ hence $$\liminf_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t e^{-1/x}\,dx\ge \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t-M}2+c=+\infty$$
hence the integral is divergent.

Comment: Your thorough answer is very helpful, thank you! I see now the mistake of just looking at the end points, especially considering the upper end "point" is never reached.. Would you say that looking at end points is fine as a method if the improper integral does not have infinity at one or more of the end points?

Comment: Yes, if $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a\in \Bbb R$, you have to check how fast $f(x)$ diverges. For instance, $f(x)\approx\, \rvert x-a\lvert^{-\beta}$ makes the improper integral diverge if $\beta\ge1$, and it makes it converge if $\beta<1$, though this does not exaust all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac 1 {e^{1/x}} =1 $ implies that for big enough values of $x$ we have $\dfrac 1 {e^{1/x}} > \dfrac 1 2$.  And therefore the integral is $\displaystyle \ge \int_a^\infty \frac 1 2 \, dx = +\infty$ (where $a$ is big enough so that $\dfrac 1 {e^{1/x}} > \dfrac 1 2$ when $x\ge a$).